# PHPUnit Testing Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I can't figure this one out in PHPUnit. In Postman it works well but in PHPUnit there is an error.

```
class MyPageTakumoiTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $api = "/api/my_page_takumoi/2";

    public function testUpdate()
    {

        $response = $this->json('PUT', $this->api, [
            'family_name' => 'new kk',
        ]);

        $response->assertStatus(200);

    }
}

Expected status code 200 but received 500.
Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 500.
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have some logs? Status 500 is a generic error status...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this at the start of your test to get a better exception:

```
$this->withoutExceptionHandling();
```

Comment: It's not the answer but it works like an answer. Thank you.